# Except() gives wrong output for two arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, except

I have two arrays, I need to display what array1 has that array2 doesn't and vice versa.

```
string[] a = { "hello", "momo" }
string[] b = { "hello"}
```

output:

```
momo
```

I am using the .Except and trying to display the output in a message box, however when i execute my code the output is this:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<ExceptIterator>d_99'1[System.Char]
```

My code:

```
//Array holding answers to test
string[] testAnswer = new string[20] { "B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A" };
string a = Convert.ToString(testAnswer);

//Reads text file line by line. Stores in array, each line of the file is an element in the array
string[] inputAnswer = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Momo\Desktop\UNI\Software tech\test.txt");
string b = Convert.ToString(inputAnswer);

//Local variables
int index = 0;
Boolean arraysequal = true;

if (testAnswer.Length != inputAnswer.Length)
{
    arraysequal = false;
}

while (arraysequal && index < testAnswer.Length)
{
    if (testAnswer[index] != inputAnswer[index])
    {
        arraysequal = false;
    }
    index++;
}

MessageBox.Show("" + a.Except(b));
```

Comment: You've run into the `object.ToString()` implementation that merely returns the type's full-name. What are you wanting from `Except`? Many are surprised to find that it's set based - so things like order and duplicates make no difference in the output.

Answer (score 5):

You should convert it to string - otherwise, it's an enumerable, and the `ToString` does not produce the expected result.

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", a.Except(b)));
```

**EDIT** The same issue exists in this line:

```
string a = Convert.ToString(testAnswer);
```

you should replace it with

```
string a = String.Join(", ", testAnswer); // << You can use a different separator
```

Comment: The same issue also exists with e.g. `string a = Convert.ToString(testAnswer);`.  A `string.Join` is the way to fix those, too.  Arrays in C# don't have a very informative `.ToString()` method (which is what `Convert.ToString` and `"" + something` both use).

Answer (score 1):

`a.Except(b)` has a type of `IEnumerable<string>` while `MessageBox.Show()` accepts `string`.

So you need to converter first two second, e.g.:

```
string output = String.Join(", ", input)`
```

will separate each element by comma.